# How to communicate with u.are.u fingerprint reader using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I am building a windows software as my final year project and in the software i need to make using of a fingerprint scanner. I got a U.are.U fingerprint scanner and which is a model of digitalpersona. Went through the software and I can't find a way of calling the APIs of the device using python which I'm programming with. please can anyone help me on how to go about this. I already have the necessary driver installed. This is the link to their GitHub repo https://github.com/iamonuwa/Digital-Persona-SDK

Comment: There are c++ examples in the SDK, you'll need to create a c++ dll with the funcitons you want to call and then use something like [SWIG to python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wrapping-cc-python-using-swig-set-1/) to create your Python dll.

Comment: okay let me give it a try